# Cannot modify html using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have made 3 `div` tags in `index.html` page:

1) div with `id="contactlist"` populate with all contact list

2) div with `id="addnewcontact"` displays subit form

3) div with `id="editcontact"` displays form to edit details

On whenever I click on `edit` button it shows the form to edit details but if I click on add button which is in upper-right corner (see screenshot) then page displays 2 forms edit form and add new form.

When I click on edit button it should only display edit form and when I click on add button in upper right corner it should only display add new contact form.

To produce above error first click on edit button and then click on add button in upper right corner.

index.html:

```
  <div id="contactlist" >

  </div>


  <div id="addnewcontact">


  </div>


  <div id="editcontact">

  </div>
```

In app.js:

```
function editContact(id) {
    document.getElementById("search").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("contactlist").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("editcontact").style.display = '';
    document.getElementById("editcontact").innerHTML = 
        `
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="InputName">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" aria-describedby="namehelp" value="`+array[id].fullName+`" >
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="InputNumber">Number</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputNumber" value="`+array[id].number+`">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="InputGroup">Group</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputGroup" value="`+array[id].group+`">
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="saveMe(`+id+`)">Submit</button>
        </form>
        `;
}


function addNew() {
    document.getElementById("search").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("contactlist").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("addnewcontact").style.display = '';
    document.getElementById("addnewcontact").innerHTML = 
    `
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputname" aria-describedby="namehelp" placeholder="Enter Name">
      </div>
       <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Number</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputnumber" aria-describedby="numberhelp" placeholder="Enter Number">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Group</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputgroup" aria-describedby="grouphelp" placeholder="Enter Group">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="submittoDB()">Submit</button>
    </form>
    `;
}


function showContacts() {
    for(var i in array){
        var id = i;
        contactlist.innerHTML +=
        `
        <ul>
        <div>
        <p>Name: `+ p1.fullName +`</p>
        <p>Number: `+ p1.number +`</p>
        <p>Group: `+ p1.group +`</p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="editContact(`+ id +`)">Edit</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
        </div>
        `
    }
}

showContacts();
```

Js fiddle live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/nca8xx6c/

[image]

Comment: Do you have any errors showing in the console?

Comment: @brotherperes No it shows 2 array objects

Comment: Can you update your question with it?

Comment: Remember that an ID attribute in HTML should be unique, so you can't have it more than once in your page officially. Besides that your JSFiddle looks different than your screenshot and gives javascript errors. Besides that it is better to already put the HTML in the page and dynamically change it when pressing edit and populate the values into the form and show it. Maybe you want to look at that first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function editContact(id) {
document.getElementById("search").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("contactlist").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("editcontact").style.display = '';
document.getElementById("addnewcontact").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("editcontact").innerHTML = 
    `
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="InputName">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" aria-describedby="namehelp" value="`+array[id].fullName+`" >
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="InputNumber">Number</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputNumber" value="`+array[id].number+`">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="InputGroup">Group</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputGroup" value="`+array[id].group+`">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="saveMe(`+id+`)">Submit</button>
    </form>
    `;
}


function addNew() {
    document.getElementById("search").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("contactlist").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("addnewcontact").style.display = '';
    document.getElementById("editcontact").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("addnewcontact").innerHTML = 
`
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputname" aria-describedby="namehelp" placeholder="Enter Name">
  </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Number</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputnumber" aria-describedby="numberhelp" placeholder="Enter Number">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Group</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputgroup" aria-describedby="grouphelp" placeholder="Enter Group">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="submittoDB()">Submit</button>
</form>
`;
}
```

Try this code snippet!.